# x-axis unorder matplotlib seabourn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code to create two bar graphs...

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8, 6), sharex=False, )

# Generate some sequential data
x1 = edu_count['Education']
y1 = edu_count['Frequency']
edu_order = ['0', '1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0', '5.0', '6.0', '7.0', '8.0', '9.0', '10.0', '11.0', '12.0', '13.0', '14.0', '15.0', '16.0', '17.0']
sns.barplot(x1, y1, color='b', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('2003 All Death By Education Level')
ax1.set_ylabel("Frequency")
ax1.set_xlabel('Education Level')


# Center the data to make it diverging
x2 = suicide_data['Education']
y2 = suicide_data['Frequency']
sns.barplot(x2, y2, color='b', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('2003 Suicide Death By Education Level')
ax2.set_ylabel("Frequency")
ax2.set_xlabel('Education Level')

# Finalize the plot
sns.despine(bottom=True)
plt.tight_layout(h_pad=2)
```

The issue I'm having is that the plot is coming sort in ascending order.

[image]

I need the x-axis in order from 0 to 17 left to right instead. I tried to use the `order=` parameter and passing the variable I have setup above but that doesn't work. Does anyone know how to disable the behavior of sorting by the values of the y-axis?

I'm doing this in Jupyter Notebook, OS X El Capitan, Python3

Comment: Why are you encoding your numbers as strings? When you give seaborn numbers, it'll put them in the correct order.

Comment: Because the original csv is not clean. I had to do some data manipulation to get to the desire stage.

Answer (score 0):

From another question I had here in `stackoverflow`; I solve the problem by sorting the data frame.

```
suicide_data['Education'] = suicide_data['Education'].astype('int')
suicide_data.sort_values(by='Education')
```

This code sorted the entire data frame by the `Education` column fixing the graph.